# grep second pattern only if the first pattern exist on a specific type of file

Tags: linux, command-line, grep

I have lots of .ini files which configures certain properties for various projects.

I want to filter for PROJECT_A in the ini file first and if that matches, then i want to filter the second pattern CONFIG_B. Since CONFIG_B is a property of PROJECT_A...X, i want to grep only the files which contains the PROJECT_A settings and CONFIG_B is also present. I know it is bit challenging, but if i can narrow down ini files with both PROJECT_A and CONFIG_A  is present, i can manually inspect them to minimum list. I have 1000 files like this :-(

Typical Config is like this

```
[F-Project:PROJECT_A]
stream-window-start=0
stream-window-end=0
network-feed=LIVE:
test-config=pdl tf_dms_hiab
```

Expected out:-

```
file1.ini
proj:PROJECT_A
cfg1:CONFIG_A
cfg1:CONFIG_B
cfg1:CONFIG_C

proj:PROJECT_B
cfg1:CONFIG_A
cfg1:CONFIG_C

file2.ini
proj:PROJECT_X
cfg1:CONFIG_A
cfg1:CONFIG_B
cfg1:CONFIG_C

proj:PROJECT_Y
cfg1:CONFIG_B
cfg1:CONFIG_C

file3.ini
proj:PROJECT_A
cfg1:CONFIG_B
cfg1:CONFIG_C

proj:PROJECT_B
cfg1:CONFIG_A
```

Results : file1.ini, file3.ini

```
find . -name *.ini -exec grep -w PROJECT_A {} \; -print | grep ini -exec grep CONFIG_A {} \;

[proj:PROJECT_A]
./PLATFORM/build/integration/suites/System_Maintenance_Suite/ini/Test_0621_1.ini
```

Since i get the output like above, im filtering only the lines containing .ini
find . -name *.ini -exec grep -w PROJECT_A {} \; -print | grep ini

```
./PLATFORM/build/integration/suites/System_Maintenance_Suite/ini/Test_0722_1.ini
./PLATFORM/build/integration/suites/System_Maintenance_Suite/ini/Test_0579_15.ini
./PLATFORM/build/integration/suites/System_Maintenance_Suite/ini/Test_0460_1.ini
```

how can i grep one line at a time for pattern CONFIG_A now

I understand i can write this to a file and read a line at a time, but i want a efficient way to do this.

Please help with your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Saying:

```
find . -name *.ini -exec sh -c "grep -q PROJECT_A {} && grep -q CONFIG_A {} && echo {}" \;
```

would list files that contain both `PROJECT_A` and `CONFIG_A`.

Using the `-q` option for `grep` would evaluate to `true` only if the specified pattern existed in the file.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. Exact form is  find . -name *.ini -exec sh -c "grep -q PROJECT_A {} && grep -q CONFIG_A {} && echo {}" \;, need to pass {} to each grep operation otherwise it hangs for ever.

Comment: @rk.infotek.ltd Of course!  Thanks for spotting that.  What will `grep` operate upon without the filenames.

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -name *.ini -exec sh -c "grep -q PROJECT_A {} && grep -q CONFIG_A {} && echo {}" \;
```

How it works ?

```
find . -name *.ini <= filters the .ini files
-exec <= executes the following command using the output from find one at a time
sh -c <= accepts string input for the shell, we need this for executing multiple commands which follws that
grep -q PROJECT_A {} <= quietly grep for PROJECT_A
grep -q PROJECT_A {} && grep -q CONFIG_A {} && echo {} <= prints the filename if both the strings are matches, simple logical and on three commands.
```

Hope it helps !!!

Comment: @JarrodRoberson hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for files where `CONFIG_B` occurs only in the stanza for `proj:PROJECT_A`, something like this?

```
find . -type f -name '*.ini' -exec awk '
    /^proj:/ { prj=$1; next }
    /CONFIG_B/ && prj="proj:PROJECT_A" {
        print FILENAME; exit 0 }' {} \;
```

... or with the "real" values from the comment below,

```
find . -type f -name '*.ini' -exec awk '
    /^F-Project:/ { prj=$1; next }
    /LIVE:/ && prj="F-Project:PROJECT_A" {
        print FILENAME; exit 0 }' {} \;
```

Comment: hi, i have updated the questions with "Typical Config is like this" which is correct form in the .ini file. The one you have given throws me awk errors.

Comment: this is the one i tried with your instruction, correct me if im wrong  find . -type f -name '*.ini' -exec awk '
    /^F-Project:/ { F-Project:$1; next }
    /LIVE:/ && F-Project="F-Project:PROJECT_A" {
        print FILENAME; exit 0 }' {} \;

Comment: No, `prj` is just the name of an Awk variable; don't rename that.

Comment: awk:  /^F-Project:/ { prj:$1; next } /LIVE:/ && F-Project="F-Project:PROJECT_A" { print FILENAME; exit 0 }
awk:                                                     ^ syntax error

Comment: Thanks for your effort, it is not working as expected. I get matches for "LIVE:" without any PROJECT_A in the file. I tried 5 different files. Sorry i wont be testing any more. Thanks any way for your help.

Answer (score 0):

What about this neat awk solution:

```
awk -vPR="PROJECT_A" -vCF="CONFIG_A" 'BEGIN{R="(" CF "|" PR ")"}
    {if($0 ~ R)d[FILENAME]+=1}
    END{for(i in d)if(d[i]>=2)print i}' file*
file3.ini
file1.ini
```

Comment: The leading and trailing wildcards are redundant.

Comment: @tripleee - thanks, also removed redundant {} after if statement  
rk.infotek.ltd - very strange double checked, and seems to work  
bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
GNU awk, 3.1.7

Comment: i got GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu), which is same :-)